Configuring LDAP client for offline login
We have installed the LDAP server on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and configured the LDAP client on a laptop. However, I am unable to log in as a user or LDAP user without a network connection.
Can anyone suggest how I can configure the LDAP client laptop so that I can log in to the laptop with an LDAP user without using the network?

I've made a few changes to your text for readability, but I'm uncertain whether I captured the meaning of the last sentence correctly.  Let me know if you meant something else.

You may want to investigate SSSD, which provides a local authentication cache so that you can still authenticate even when offline.
